# QT HTTP POST, but found a POST HTTP packet split into one HTTP and one TCP

Tags: qt, http

using QT to send a HTTP post (text/xml or json or whatever), the post will be done as:
a http packet, then a tcp packet which contains the real what i want to send out.

Why?

```
QUrl urlDigital("http://data.service.com");
QNetworkAccessManager *sfsmanager;
QNetworkRequest sfsrequest;

sfsrequest.setUrl(urlDigital);
sfsrequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,QVariant("multipart/form-data"));
sfsrequest.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, pstring.size());
sfsreply = sfsmanager->post(sfsrequest, pstring);
```

The post is like

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    264 30.182185000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net TCP      62     50610→http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 264: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 0, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    267 30.209442000   waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         TCP      62     http→50610 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4380 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1

Frame 267: 62 bytes on wire (496 bits), 62 bytes captured (496 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 0, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    268 30.209563000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net TCP      54     50610→http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=0

Frame 268: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    269 30.210532000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net HTTP     268    POST / HTTP/1.1

Frame 269: 268 bytes on wire (2144 bits), 268 bytes captured (2144 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 214
Hypertext Transfer Protocol

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    272 30.239414000   waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         TCP      54     http→50610 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=215 Win=4594 Len=0

Frame 272: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 1, Ack: 215, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    273 30.239503000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net TCP      870    50610→http [PSH, ACK] Seq=215 Ack=1 Win=64240 Len=816

Frame 273: 870 bytes on wire (6960 bits), 870 bytes captured (6960 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 215, Ack: 1, Len: 816

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    275 30.273341000   waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         TCP      60     http→50610 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1031 Win=5410 Len=0

Frame 275: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 1, Ack: 1031, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    292 30.970985000   waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         HTTP     461    HTTP/1.1 302 Found

Frame 292: 461 bytes on wire (3688 bits), 461 bytes captured (3688 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 1, Ack: 1031, Len: 407
Hypertext Transfer Protocol

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    293 31.032033000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net TCP      54     50610→http [ACK] Seq=1031 Ack=408 Win=63833 Len=0

Frame 293: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1031, Ack: 408, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    454 47.572699000   192.168.10.10         waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net HTTP     381    POST /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F HTTP/1.1

Frame 454: 381 bytes on wire (3048 bits), 381 bytes captured (3048 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1), Dst: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10), Dst: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 50610 (50610), Dst Port: http (80), Seq: 1031, Ack: 408, Len: 327
Hypertext Transfer Protocol

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
    455 47.602155000   waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         TCP      60     http→50610 [ACK] Seq=408 Ack=1358 Win=5737 Len=0

Frame 455: 60 bytes on wire (480 bits), 60 bytes captured (480 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 408, Ack: 1358, Len: 0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
   1648 165.327426000  waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net 192.168.10.10         TCP      54     http→50610 [RST, ACK] Seq=408 Ack=1358 Win=5737 Len=0

Frame 1648: 54 bytes on wire (432 bits), 54 bytes captured (432 bits) on interface 0
Ethernet II, Src: 4c:60:de:36:8a:f7 (4c:60:de:36:8a:f7), Dst: c0:14:3d:de:09:a1 (c0:14:3d:de:09:a1)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: waws-prod-sg1-005.cloudapp.net (23.101.27.182), Dst: 192.168.10.10 (192.168.10.10)
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: http (80), Dst Port: 50610 (50610), Seq: 408, Ack: 1358, Len: 0

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is application layer protocol, TCP is transport layer protocol. Most HTTP traffic travels over TCP